# ActiveX Control "Creation Failed"

Tags: c#, activex, activexobject

I have a class that inherits from AxHost, after I initialize an instance of the class, I call CreateControl :

```
  AxBioBridgeSDKLib.AxBioBridgeSDK axBioBridgeSDK1 = new AxBioBridgeSDKLib.AxBioBridgeSDK();

    axBioBridgeSDK1.CreateControl();
```

Which will throw an error "Creatin Failed".

After this the appliction continues to run normally and I get "AccessViolationException" , "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"
on the following line :

```
  axBioBridgeSDK1.SetDeviceCommKey(0);
```

I use .NET framework 3.5 with VS 2010 on 64 bit system.
I have tried many issues such as:

- Unregister and re-register the OCX files.
- use the command "netsh winsock reset"
- Change the configuration of the project to X86

I suspect that it is something related to 32/64 configuration, and that the second error is caused because of the first one. Thanks,

Comment: You are just writing bad code, an ActiveX control must always have a valid Parent property.  Whose IsHandleCreated property is *true* and created on an STA thread that pumps a message loop.  Trivially done by dropping the control on a winforms Form.  It doesn't have to be visible.  Contact the vendor if you want to use it "headless".

Comment: the problem is that this code came from the vendor !! do u have any idea what code should I add in order to solve?